# React component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, components, warnings

Having the following React Component for Custom Checkbox where values are passed down as props from parent

```
export const CheckBox = (props) => {
  let closeClass;

  if (!props.hint && props.hint == "") {
    closeClass = "no-hint";
  }
  return (
    <div className={"field-wrapper checkbox-button-grouped"}>
      <label htmlFor={`checkbox_${props.value}`}>
        <input
          onChange={props.handleCheckChieldElement}
          type="checkbox"
          name={props.name}
          id={`checkbox_${props.value}`}
          className={"input-field"}
          checked={props.isChecked}
          value={props.value || ""}
        />
        <div className="label-text">
          <div className={"label-name"}>{props.label}</div>
          {props.hint && props.hint !== "" ? (
            <div className={"info-icon"}>
              <InfoIcon className={"info-icon"} />
            </div>
          ) : null}
          <div className={"hint"}>{props.hint}</div>
          <UncheckIcon className={classnames("uncheck", closeClass)} />
          <Checkmark className={"ok-icon"} />
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CheckBox;
```

I keep getting the following error

`Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.`

What I'm doing wrong in this case?

Comment: You can try: `checked={Boolean(props.isChecked)}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`props.isChecked` is probably null or undefined, you can solve it like this:

```
checked={props.isChecked || false}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled

If you are getting this error, it means that the value you are providing to the input field is not updated by your onChange function.

The value state that is assigned to any input should be only modified through the onChange function else you get this warning.

It is also possible that the value is undefined as soon as the onChange action is performed.

As of your case declare

> isChecked as a boolean with initial value as false or true as you like.

If you are using hook

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState(false);
```

for class component

```
this.state = {
   isChecked: false
}
```

Here is the working code in code sandbox [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-firefly-6scio?file=/src/App.js)